# How to modify when Vue CLI's WebPack CSS/SCSS loaders process data passed via `prependData`?

Tags: webpack, sass, vuejs3, sass-loader, vue-cli-4

I have a collection of variables in a JSON file that I'm trying to share between styles (SCSS) and my Vue 3 (using the Vue CLI) environment.

**./vars.json**

```
{
  "foo": 123,
  "bar": "abc"
}
```

Getting the JSON into the script side's consciousness is the easy part. I'm stumped as to how to get the variables into the SCSS. According to the reference ([Vue CLI Docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders), among them) I could find online, my best bet is injecting them via `prependData` in the `sass` (loader) configuration in `vue.config.js`.

**vue.config.js**

```
const varData = require( "./vars.json" );

function jsonVarHelper() {
  let string = "";
  for (var variableName in varData) {
    string += `$${variableName}: ${varData[variableName]};\n`;
  }
  return string;
}

module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: `@import "@/styles/main.scss";\n${jsonVarHelper()}`
      }
    }
  }
};
```

… which *is* rendering `"$foo: 123;\n' + '$bar: abc;\n'"` — which I confirmed by spitting out a `console.log( {string} )` in `jsonVarHelper`. It was further confirmed in that I could use the variables in the Vue components' `<style>` sections.

**./src/App.vue** (omitting `<template>` and `<script>` for brevity)

```
<style lang="scss">
#app::after {
  content: "#{ $bar }"; // appends "abc" as expected
}
</style>
```

Sure enough, `#app` has the string "abc" appended to it in the compiled page. Great, right? Problem solved…

**But**, when I try to reference the variables in `*.scss` files, WebPack throws a syntax error.

**./src/styles/main.scss**

```
#baz::after {
  content: "#{ $bar }"; // throws `Syntax Error: SassError: Undefined variable: "$bar".`
}
```

I'm guessing this is a matter of *when* the `scss-loader` is prepending the data from the `prependData` configuration. Is it possible to have it parse/inject that string *before* it tries to compile the native `*.scss` files?

Comment: What is your sass-loader's version ?

Comment: @小聪聪到此一游 It is 8.0.2